# Angular template variable with calculation

Tags: angular

In angularjs you could do:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div ng-init="a=1 + 5 -2">{{a}}
  </div>
</div>
```

//a = 4

Whats the equivalent in angular 5/6/7?
I have a ngFor loop with number, and I need to present at the bottom the total number.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let i of arr">{{random()}}</div>
  <b>Total: _____?</b>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  arr = new Array(10)
  random(){
    return  Math.floor((Math.random()*10));
  }
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ij5uxc

Thanks

Comment: why not call a function and pass value to it

Answer (score 1):

You should rely on event programming. Start using RxJS to its full potential !

In [this sackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a737nc?file=src/app/app.component.ts) I show you how to do it : create a `Subject` that is an array of your values. You then create a second observable that is the total sum of the values of the array.

With this solution, you can just push a new value to your array, and it automatically gets updated in your view thanks to the `async` pipe.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <button (click)="addValueToSub()">
      Add a new value to the array
    </button>
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let value of (sub | async)">{{value}}</div>
  <b>Total ? {{ total | async }} !</b>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  sub = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  total = this.sub.pipe(
    map(values => values.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0))
  );

  constructor() {
    for (const i of new Array(10)) {
      this.addValueToSub();
    }
  }

  random() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
  }

  addValueToSub(value = this.random()) {
    this.sub.pipe(
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(values => {
      values.push(value);
      this.sub.next(values);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any Global variable and add every time you generate random number like below -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let i of arr">{{random()}}</div>
  <b>Total: {{total}}?</b>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  arr = new Array(10)
  total = 0;
  random(){
    this.total += Math.floor((Math.random()*10));
    return this.total  
  }
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would generate an array of random numbers and then just use a function to calculate the sum, see example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evatxk?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

```
arr: number[] = [];
arrayLength = 0;

ngOnInit() {    
  while (this.arrayLength < 10) {
    this.arr[this.arrayLength] = this.random();
    this.arrayLength++;
  }
}

random(): number {
  return  Math.floor((Math.random()*10));
}  

getTotal(): number {
  return this.arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
}
```